# .NET Web Service called from jQuery Ajax not handling encoded query strings

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax

I have a simple .NET [asmx] web service setup like this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
public string Find(string stateAbbrev, string city, string name) 
{
   // Code
}
```

I call this web method from this:

```
           $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                cache: false,
                url: "/webservice.asmx/Find",
                data: { stateAbbrev: "'" + escape(self.selectedState()) + "'", city: "'" + escape(self.city()) + "'", name: "'" + escape(self.name()) + "'" },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function() { }
              });
```

I've tried several variations with the above url/data parameters.  Including encodeURI, encodeURIComponent and escape.  The problem is that the data encoded on the client side is not being handled on the server properly.  What I mean is that when I encode/escape the query strings, I end up with a HTTP GET request like this:

```
http://localhost/webservice.asmx/Find?stateAbbrev=''&city='MyCity%2527'&name=''
```

The %2527 is an escaped character.  The server handles this that the city name is actually "MyCity%2527".

Do I need to do anything on the server itself, or should the decoding of query strings be handled by .NET?  Am I doing the encoding correctly?

Thank You,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way I could get around this was to use a HTTP 'POST' instead of a 'GET', since POSTing will automatically encode the data sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a variable to get the value for self.selectedState(), from there you can check if there are excess characters on the value. then pass the variable to ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Change the data line to this:

```
            data: { stateAbbrev: escape(self.selectedState()), city: escape(self.city()) , name:escape(self.name()) },
```

You dont have to qoute it...

Or if you want to send it like JSON you could try with

```
data: JSON.stringify({ stateAbbrev: escape(self.selectedState()), city: escape(self.city()) , name:escape(self.name()) }),
```